# LastInsertId gives back 0

Tags: php, sql

When I try to add an INSERT INTO to push data into my database it wasn't adding anything. Noticed that lastInsertId didn't work. Gives back 0.

The funny part I had this problem couple of days ago and fixed it by deleting the table and add a new one but that's not working this time. I am using Auto Increment on ID.

I know I can retrieve information by using SELECT so I know I got the connection to my database.

This is how I built up my query:

```
public function tools(){
  $filename = $_POST['namefile'];
    $this->query("SELECT * FROM page_context WHERE file_name='kalm'");
    $rows = $this->resultSet();

    if(isset($_POST["sendFile"])) {
        $this->query("INSERT INTO page_context(file_name) VALUES(:file_name)");
        $this->bind(':file_name' , $filename);
        $this->execute();
        print_r($this->lastInsertId()); //0
        if($this->lastInsertId()){  //Doesn't get executed because no value
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'home/pageContext/'.$filename);
            return;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The first part was just a test if a connection is made.

and this is how lastInsertId is built up.

```
public function lastInsertId(){
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}
```

Saw enough on stackoverflow and other sites but most of the time it was a typo or just like that. I can't pinpoint the problem why lastInsertId is 0.

**EDIT!**

This is my constructor which works fine because I can retrieve other information where I call a specific item(UPDATE ? WHERE ?). I got the connection up on running only I can't pass data because of id not working.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}
```

Comment: which framework you are using? your answer relies on the class in which `$this->dbh` is instantiated

Comment: is it typo `$this->dbh` or `$this->db`

Comment: Is there something in the table you're trying to get lastInsertId() from?

Comment: Is the new row added or not? What is the table's definition? What data is already in the DB? What happens if you try to execute the insert directly (phpmyadmin or whatever)?

Comment: I make a good connection. That's not the problem.

Comment: @JiriTousek I'm not able to add anything from my PHP. I am able to insert directly into phpmyadmin. So it's a php problem for sure. At the moment I have 1 row of data with id 1. Removed it and try php again and nothing worked. Removed table and add the table again and still no succes and afterwards I did the query directly and that works on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Menazanie isn't it normal that lastInsertId() returns 0 if the table is empty?

Comment: @PascalClaes True but it's not empty. I got a row of data in the table

Answer (score 1):

i think first of all you should check if the insert clause has actually happened that the data has been inserted to the database,

if yes:

then the problem is in this line `$this->lastInsertId()` and i would recommend to check this 'dbh' class

if No:

then the problem comes from this line

```
$this->query("INSERT INTO page_context(file_name) VALUES(:file_name)");
```

if you can tell us more about which framework are you using we can debug the query.

however i would recommend try also to insert static value and see if it works 
like

`$this->query("INSERT INTO page_context(file_name) VALUES(some static value)");`

Comment: solution 1: See edit on top. Solution 2: Specify a bit more what you mean with: tell more about the framework. You mean the connection between the files or just the whole framework?